# JAX jax.grad on simple function that takes an array: `ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected`

Tags: python, numpy, jax, autograd

I'm trying to implement this function and use JAX to automatically build the gradient function:

```
$f(x) = \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n-1} [100 (x_{k+1} - x_k^2)^2 + (1 - x_k)^2]$
```

(sorry, I don't know how to format math on stackoverflow. Some sister sites allow TeX, but apparently this site does not?)

```py
import jax
import jax.numpy as jnp

# x is an array, which does not handle type hints well.
def rosenbrock(n: int, x: any) -> float:
    f = 0
    # i is 1-indexed to match document.
    for i in range(1, n):
        # adjust 1-based indices to 0-based python indices.
        xi = x[i-1].item()
        xip1 = x[i].item()

        fi = 100 * (xip1 - xi**2)**2 + (1 - xi)**2
        f = f + fi
    return f


# with n=2.
def rosenbrock2(x: any) -> float:
    return rosenbrock(2, x)


grad_rosenbrock2 = jax.grad(rosenbrock2)

x = jnp.array([-1.2, 1], dtype=jnp.float32).reshape(2,1)

# this line fails with the error given below
grad_rosenbrock2(x)
```

This last line results in:

```
ConcretizationTypeError: Abstract tracer value encountered where concrete value is expected: traced array with shape float32[1].
The problem arose with the `float` function. If trying to convert the data type of a value, try using `x.astype(float)` or `jnp.array(x, float)` instead.

See https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/errors.html#jax.errors.ConcretizationTypeError
```

I'm trying to follow the docs, and I'm confused. This is my first time using JAX or Autograd, can someone help me resolve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `.item()` method attempts to convert an array to a static Python scalar, and since you have traced arrays within your `grad` transformation, conversion to a static value is not possible.

What you need here is to convert a size-1 array to a scalar array, which you can do using `.reshape(())`:

```py
def rosenbrock(n: int, x: any) -> float:
    f = 0
    # i is 1-indexed to match document.
    for i in range(1, n):
        # adjust 1-based indices to 0-based python indices.
        xi = x[i-1].reshape(())
        xip1 = x[i].reshape(())

        fi = 100 * (xip1 - xi**2)**2 + (1 - xi)**2
        f = f + fi
    return f
```

For more background on jax transformations and traced arrays, I'd recommend [How to think in JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/thinking_in_jax.html).

Comment: Thank you. When I change to `.reshape()`, `rosenbrock2(x)` returns `Array(24.200005, dtype=float32)` rather than a simple scalar. maybe i can get around that but then if I do `jax.hessian(rosenbrock2)(x).shape` I get `(2,1,2,1)` rather than a simple 2x2 Hessian like I'd expect. The error message goes away though.

Comment: Both are as expected: scalars in JAX are represented as zero-dimensional arrays. `Array(24.200005, dtype=float32)` is a zero-dimensional array representing the scalar output. Regarding the hessian, the output shape will be `(*out.shape, *x.shape, *x.shape)`. Since your input has shape `(2, 1)` and your output has shape `()` (a scalar), the hessian will have shape `(2, 1, 2, 1)`. If you want the hessian to be of shape `(2, 2)`, then your input should be of shape `(2,)` for a function with scalar output.